# MySQL Subquery to SELECT from another table

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'd like to create a query like that looks up a value from another table if the value of a particular field is not 0.  Like this?

```
SELECT id, name, type, site_id
   IF (site_id > 0)
     THEN (SELECT id FROM setups WHERE setups.id = image.site_id) as site
     ELSE "" as site
FROM image
  ORDER BY image.id
```

Can someone help me with the syntax for doing the SELECT in the middle, only if the value of `site_id` is not 0 and based on the value of `site_id`.  If the site_id = 0, I need return an empty string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery and a `case` (which I prefer to the `if` function):

```
SELECT i.id, i.name, i.type, i.site_id,
       (CASE WHEN i.site_id > 0
            THEN (SELECT s.id FROM setups s WHERE s.id = i.site_id)
            ELSE ''
        END) as site
FROM image i
ORDER BY i.id
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Most helpful,  unfortunately I have struck another problem I need to get my head around. I will be back . :)

Answer (score 0):

if you need the related id from setups i recommend:

```
SELECT `image`.`id`, `image`.`name`, `image`.`type`, `setups`.`id` as site_id FROM `image`, `setups` WHERE `setups`.`id`=`image`.`site_id`
```

If **site_id** is 0 its will be descarted, only the matching rows will be showed, the subqueries are very slow compared whit joins